# Incorrect answer in RE2::FullMatch

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I am trying to use RE2::FullMatch but I get incorrect answer.

When I do this, I get true:

```
re2::RE2 regex("[sS]omename");
std::string input="somename";
re2::RE2::FullMatch(input, regex);
```

But if I want to extracts the result into variable, I get false

```
re2::RE2 regex("[sS]omename");
std::string input="somename";
std::string match_result;
re2::RE2::FullMatch(input, regex, &match_result);
```

What can be the problem in the second way ?

Comment: From the documentation it looks like any arguments are for capturing *sub* matches. So your regex should contain a capturing group somewhere, eg `([sS]omename)`

Comment: what can I do for getting the result in to the string ?

Comment: Wrap the regex in a capturing group (the `()`)

Comment: if you're doing a `FullMatch` then by definition  `match_result` == `input` if the return value is `true`